# PrestaShop, get ID when insert in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a script for PrestaShop 1.6 that inserts data into a table.
My table is made in this way:

- id: int AUTO INCREMENT
- desc: string

As I enter a description I would get back the ID value.

On can not use the standard because it blocked by PrestaShop.

I find this a situation:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `"._DB_PREFIX_."table`(`desc`) VALUES ('".$this->desc."')";
$restpo = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
var_dump($restpo);
```

But I have an answer only a boolean. 
Can you suggest something?

Comment: You can't retrieve last inserted id from execute method. But you can use this method: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the:

```
$id = (int)Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

For example, in the Cart class:

```
$last_id = (int)Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

I also recommend the use of the function insert, for example in the Carrier class:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($shops as $id_shop) {
      $values[] = array(
           'id_carrier' => (int)$this->id,
           'id_tax_rules_group' => (int)$id_tax_rules_group,
           'id_shop' => (int)$id_shop,
       );
}
$res = Db::getInstance()->insert('carrier_tax_rules_group_shop', $values);
```

Then use the Insert_ID to get the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$id = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();` after executing your SQL.

Answer (score 2):

PrestaShop's `DB` class provides the [last inserted id](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices#DBclassbestpractices-Afewothermethods) via

```
Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

method.